# How to transport second-hand stuff in Denmark

Tags: relocation, denmark

I checked every stack overflow community and this one seemed me the best fit. In Denmark, there are many second hand goods shops.

I rent a house and am looking for almost everything. Some of those are big items, like living room furniture.

After I make a deal, are there any companies in the Odense, Denmark area which will deliver items like big living room furniture and for reasonable price?

Comment: One could construe second-hand stuff to be on-topic on Sustainable Living?

Comment: @gerrit agree, but it's really about finding a delivery service in Odense. Kadir, have you visited any of the shops. Often, they'll either have such a service, for an added fee, or know to whom to refer you. Shop first, ask if it delivers, and what options there are.

Comment: @Dorothy I didn't check them yet. The one that I like is online. Forexample this one https://www.guloggratis.dk/inde/mobler/senge/dobbeltseng/annonce/billeder/35498008-dobbeltsengikeamalm.    Than I found that website http://app.fragtopgaver.dk/ . Which you can describe what you will carry and stuff than they will give you a price. I created my scenario and waiting for a price now.

Comment: @gerrit while checking all the stack overflow communities I checked this one as well. Since my problem is related with price more than the environment I thought this should go here.

Comment: "Reasonable price" is always something relative. As for Denmark, I suppose that even reasonable price for transport might easily exceed the price of 2nd hand furniture.

Comment: Unfortuantely there's not an SE for everything, and this isn't a problem exclusive to Expats, sorry :/